# How to get data from two table on basis of two column match

Tags: php, mysql

i have a three table Userregistration,paytransaction and requesttransaction in which i have to get data from all the table with same userid and mobile number in which i have get following details of fromuser and touser like fromname,fromnumber,fromemail and details of touser is toname,tonumber but i was unable to get email id of to user also and it will find on basis of contact number.Below is my table structure.

Userregistration

```
id   contactname    mobile_no     email
.................................................
5     varun         8817          abc@gmail.com
112   chetan        1234          def@gmail.com
```

paytransaction

```
id userid  fromname  fromnumber tocontactname   tocontactnumber  status
...........................................................................
1    5       varun     8817       chetan           1234            pay
```

requesttransaction

```
id userid  fromname  fromnumber tocontactname   tocontactnumber  status
...........................................................................
1    112    chetan     1234       varun           8817        request
2    112    chetan     1234       ankit           123         request
```

I want this output if user is register in user table then get email id otherwise comeblank

```
id userid  fromname  fromnumber  fromemail       tocontactname    tocontactnumber  toemail       status
    ...........................................................................
1    5     varun      8817       abc@gmail.com        chetan           1234      def@gmail.com   pay
3   112    chetan     1234      def@gmail.com          varun           8817      abc@gmail.com   request
4   112    chetan     1234      def@gmail.com           ankit           123                      request
```

here ankit user is not registered so his toemail id come as blank and i have used below query but i was unable to find toemailid on basis of cotactnumber.i have tried the below query but i was unable to get toemail id.

```
SELECT Userregistration.`id`,paytransaction.`id`,paytransaction.`userid`,paytransaction.`fromname`,paytransaction.`fromnumber`,Userregistration.email as fromemail,paytransaction.`contactname` as toname,paytransaction.`contactnumber` as tonumber FROM `paytransaction` INNER JOIN Userregistration ON paytransaction.`userid`=Userregistration.`id` UNION SELECT Userregistration.`id`,requesttransaction.`id`,requesttransaction.`userid`,requesttransaction.`fromname`,requesttransaction.`fromnumber`,Userregistration.email as fromemail,requesttransaction.`contactname` as toname,requesttransaction.`contactnumber` as tonumber FROM `requesttransaction` INNER JOIN Userregistration ON requesttransaction.`userid`=Userregistration.`id`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly what youwant obtain you should use two inner join and not an union

```
SELECT 
    a.`id`
    ,requesttransaction.`id`
    ,requesttransaction.`userid`
    ,requesttransaction.`fromname`
    ,requesttransaction.`fromnumber`, 
    ,a.email as fromemail 
    ,requesttransaction.`toname`
    ,requesttransaction.`tonumber`,         
    ,b.email as toemail 
    ,requesttransaction.`contactname` as toname2
    ,requesttransaction.`contactnumber` as tonumber2
    FROM requesttransaction
    left JOIN Userregistration as a  ON requesttransaction.`fromnumber`= a.`mobile_no` 
    left JOIN Userregistration as b  ON requesttransaction.`tonumber`= b.`mobile_no`
```

Comment: Hi there is an lots of error in query i am not unable to run this.

Comment: yes it is working fine but it only give the data if fromuser and touser both are registered but i want if to user is not registered in useregistration table then it give blank in place of toemail id but it should return the remaining field i have mentioned this in my question like ankit is not regitered but then it gives the data of other field.

Comment: I have update the answer for not register user  too .